# Numeric Input Unsupporetd Amazon Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

On creating a new intent with utterance 99110, I get the following error

> "1099" in utterance "1099" for intent "numericTest" contains an unsupported character or word. An utterance can consist only of Unicode characters, spaces, and valid punctuation marks. Valid punctuation marks are: periods for abbreviations, underscores, apostrophes, and hyphens. If there is a slot placeholder in your utterance ensure, that it's in the {slotName} format and has spaces at both ends.

lex doesn't send this to the lambda instance because it fails to evaluate intent. I can handle the input at the lambda if I get input, but lex just returns a "Sorry, I didn't understand that."

How do I get this numeric input to my lambda instance, or how do I get lex to recognize this number?

The documentation says use amazon.NUMBER inbuilt intent, but it's not there anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Amazon, utterances can be spoken or typed words and phrases.

Instead of literally putting "1099" as the utterance, you can write "one oh nine nine" or "one zero nine nine" and it will work if the user types "1099" as text or speaks it.